# How to re-import Disqus exported comments

Tags: disqus

We kind of messed up our comments using Disqus migration tool, now we need to recover from a backup. The problem is, Disqus won't import the files it exported.

Does anyone already have a script to convert Disqus format to some format it supports importing, e.g. WXR?

Or is there any other way to do that?